# Как запустить стрим на ffmpeg с захватом экрана?

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg, capture

У меня есть сервер [nms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-media-server) в котором сказано как я могу делать трансляцию с помощью чистого ffmpeg
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же 10 минут поисков и можно найти как записывать экран c помощью [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop) 
Но при попытке связать первую команду с первого источника с записью экрана возникает ошибка

```
[flv @ 000002607d95aa40] Video codec bmp not compatible with flv
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Function not implemented
```

Не долго думая понимаем что проблема с файлом, и берем второй кусочек кода, и уже в этом случае становится успешно установить соединение, но в папке где должны откладываться чанки, и прочие файлы для hls - не создаются, да и сам сервер совершает дисконнект, как делать запись экрана и отправлять ее сразу на rtmp сервер?

Сама команда выглядит так:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -offset_x 1-offset_y 1-video_size 640x480 -show_region 1 -re -i desktop -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/newStream
```

Answer (score 0):

Требовалось просто указать буферное время.

```
-rtbufsize [number]M
```